# Can not run vstest.console.exe for Windows Store app on Azure Windows 8.1

Tags: visual-studio, azure, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, vstest

When i trying to launch it it breaks with error:

```
C:\Users\xakpc\.jenkins\workspace\App>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mi
crosoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vst
est.console.exe" "src\App\App.Tests\AppPackages\App.Tests_1.0.
0.0_x86_Debug_Test\App.Tests_1.0.0.0_x86_Debug.appx" /UseVsixExtensions:false /Platform:x86 /Logger:trx /InIsolation
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 12.0.30723.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...

Error: Unit tests for Windows Store apps cannot be run from BUILTIN\administrato
r or TR\xakpc user accounts. Please run tests using a user account fro
m which process with medium and low privileges can be launched.
```

Does anyone has any ideas what can cause this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was quite a funny.

Error message

> Error: Unit tests for Windows Store apps cannot be run from
>   BUILTIN\administrato r or TR\xakpc user accounts. Please run tests
>   using a user account fro m which process with medium and low
>   privileges can be launched.

means that i need simple local user (not administrator) account to run tests. I created new user without admin rights and tests works fine.